# problema con estilo css en menu vertical

Tags: css

Tengo problema con CSS que no cubre el 100% de un menu vertical
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

los estilos son

```css
/*     General overwrite     */
body {
  color: #66615b;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: 'Muli', Arial, sans-serif;
}
body .wrapper {
  min-height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}


/*           Animations              */
.form-control,
.input-group-addon,
.tagsinput,
.navbar,
.navbar .alert {
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms linear;
  -moz-transition: all 300ms linear;
  -o-transition: all 300ms linear;
  -ms-transition: all 300ms linear;
  transition: all 300ms linear;
}

.sidebar .nav a,
.table > tbody > tr .td-actions .btn {
  -webkit-transition: all 150ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: all 150ms ease-in;
  -o-transition: all 150ms ease-in;
  -ms-transition: all 150ms ease-in;
  transition: all 150ms ease-in;
}

.btn {
  -webkit-transition: all 100ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: all 100ms ease-in;
  -o-transition: all 100ms ease-in;
  -ms-transition: all 100ms ease-in;
  transition: all 100ms ease-in;
}

.fa {
  width: 21px;
  text-align: center;
}

.fa-base {
  font-size: 1.25em !important;
}

.margin-top {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

hr {
  border-color: #F1EAE0;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}

.sidebar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}
.sidebar .sidebar-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  max-height: none;
  min-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 260px;
  z-index: 4;
  box-shadow: inset -1px 0px 0px 0px #DDDDDD;
}
.sidebar .sidebar-background {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}

.sidebar,
.off-canvas-sidebar {
  width: 260px;
  display: block;
  font-weight: 200;
}
.sidebar .logo,
.off-canvas-sidebar .logo {
  padding: 18px 0px;
  margin: 0 20px;
}
.sidebar .logo p,
.off-canvas-sidebar .logo p {
  float: left;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 10px 10px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
.sidebar .logo .simple-text,
.off-canvas-sidebar .logo .simple-text {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 4px 0px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 30px;
}
.sidebar .nav,
.off-canvas-sidebar .nav {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.sidebar .nav li > a,
.off-canvas-sidebar .nav li > a {
  margin: 10px 0px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  opacity: .7;
}
.sidebar .nav li:hover > a,
.off-canvas-sidebar .nav li:hover > a {
  opacity: 1;
}
.sidebar .nav li.active > a,
.off-canvas-sidebar .nav li.active > a {
  color: #7A9E9F;
  opacity: 1;
}
.sidebar .nav li.active > a:before,
.off-canvas-sidebar .nav li.active > a:before {
  border-right: 17px solid #DDDDDD;
  border-top: 17px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 17px solid transparent;
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 8px;
}
.sidebar .nav li.active > a:after,
.off-canvas-sidebar .nav li.active > a:after {
  border-right: 17px solid #f4f3ef;
  border-top: 17px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 17px solid transparent;
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  right: -1px;
  top: 8px;
}
.sidebar .nav p,
.off-canvas-sidebar .nav p {
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.sidebar .nav i,
.off-canvas-sidebar .nav i {
  font-size: 24px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 15px;
  line-height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
.sidebar:after, .sidebar:before,
.off-canvas-sidebar:after,
.off-canvas-sidebar:before {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  background: #FFFFFF;
}
.sidebar:after, .sidebar:before, .sidebar[data-background-color="white"]:after, .sidebar[data-background-color="white"]:before,
.off-canvas-sidebar:after,
.off-canvas-sidebar:before,
.off-canvas-sidebar[data-background-color="white"]:after,
.off-canvas-sidebar[data-background-color="white"]:before {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
.sidebar .logo, .sidebar[data-background-color="white"] .logo,
.off-canvas-sidebar .logo,
.off-canvas-sidebar[data-background-color="white"] .logo {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(102, 97, 91, 0.3);
}
.sidebar .logo p, .sidebar[data-background-color="white"] .logo p,
.off-canvas-sidebar .logo p,
.off-canvas-sidebar[data-background-color="white"] .logo p {
  color: #66615B;
}
.sidebar .logo .simple-text, .sidebar[data-background-color="white"] .logo .simple-text,
.off-canvas-sidebar .logo .simple-text,
.off-canvas-sidebar[data-background-color="white"] .logo .simple-text {
  color: #66615B;
}
.sidebar .nav li:not(.active) > a, .sidebar[data-background-color="white"] .nav li:not(.active) > a,
.off-canvas-sidebar .nav li:not(.active) > a,
.off-canvas-sidebar[data-background-color="white"] .nav li:not(.active) > a {
  color: #66615B;
}
.sidebar .nav .divider, .sidebar[data-background-color="white"] .nav .divider,
.off-canvas-sidebar .nav .divider,
.off-canvas-sidebar[data-background-color="white"] .nav .divider {
  background-color: rgba(102, 97, 91, 0.2);
}
.sidebar[data-background-color="black"]:after, .sidebar[data-background-color="black"]:before,
.off-canvas-sidebar[data-background-color="black"]:after,
.off-canvas-sidebar[data-background-color="black"]:before {
  background-color: #212120;
}
.sidebar[data-background-color="black"] .logo,
.off-canvas-sidebar[data-background-color="black"] .logo {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}
.sidebar[data-background-color="black"] .logo p,
.off-canvas-sidebar[data-background-color="black"] .logo p {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
.sidebar[data-background-color="black"] .logo .simple-text,
.off-canvas-sidebar[data-background-color="black"] .logo .simple-text {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
.sidebar[data-background-color="black"] .nav li:not(.active) > a,
.off-canvas-sidebar[data-background-color="black"] .nav li:not(.active) > a {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
.sidebar[data-background-color="black"] .nav .divider,
.off-canvas-sidebar[data-background-color="black"] .nav .divider {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}
.sidebar[data-active-color="primary"] .nav li.active > a,
.off-canvas-sidebar[data-active-color="primary"] .nav li.active > a {
  color: #7A9E9F;
  opacity: 1;
}
.sidebar[data-active-color="info"] .nav li.active > a,
.off-canvas-sidebar[data-active-color="info"] .nav li.active > a {
  color: #68B3C8;
  opacity: 1;
}
.sidebar[data-active-color="success"] .nav li.active > a,
.off-canvas-sidebar[data-active-color="success"] .nav li.active > a {
  color: #7AC29A;
  opacity: 1;
}
.sidebar[data-active-color="warning"] .nav li.active > a,
.off-canvas-sidebar[data-active-color="warning"] .nav li.active > a {
  color: #F3BB45;
  opacity: 1;
}
.sidebar[data-active-color="danger"] .nav li.active > a,
.off-canvas-sidebar[data-active-color="danger"] .nav li.active > a {
  color: #EB5E28;
  opacity: 1;
}
.main-panel .navbar {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.sidebar,
.main-panel {
  overflow: auto;
  max-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transition-property: top,bottom;
  transition-property: top,bottom;
  -webkit-transition-duration: .2s,.2s;
  transition-duration: .2s,.2s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: linear,linear;
  transition-timing-function: linear,linear;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
   
.dropdown-menu {
  background-color: #FFFCF5;
  border: 0 none;
  border-radius: 6px;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 9000;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px rgba(17, 16, 15, 0.1), 0 2px 10px rgba(17, 16, 15, 0.1);
  box-shadow: 0 2px rgba(17, 16, 15, 0.1), 0 2px 10px rgba(17, 16, 15, 0.1);
}
.open .dropdown-menu {
  opacity: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  visibility: visible;
}
.dropdown-menu .divider {
  background-color: #F1EAE0;
  margin: 0px;
}
.dropdown-menu .dropdown-header {
  color: #9A9A9A;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}
.select .dropdown-menu {
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% -40px;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% -40px;
  -o-transform-origin: 50% -40px;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% -40px;
  transform-origin: 50% -40px;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1);
  -o-transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
  -webkit-transition: all 150ms linear;
  -moz-transition: all 150ms linear;
  -o-transition: all 150ms linear;
  -ms-transition: all 150ms linear;
  transition: all 150ms linear;
  margin-top: -20px;
}
.select.open .dropdown-menu {
  margin-top: -1px;
}
.dropdown-menu > li > a {
  color: #66615b;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  -webkit-transition: none;
  -moz-transition: none;
  -o-transition: none;
  -ms-transition: none;
  transition: none;
}
.dropdown-menu > li > a img {
  margin-top: -3px;
}
.dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
  outline: 0 !important;
}
.dropdown-menu > li:first-child > a {
  border-top-left-radius: 6px;
  border-top-right-radius: 6px;
}
.dropdown-menu > li:last-child > a {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
}
.select .dropdown-menu > li:first-child > a {
  border-radius: 0;
  border-bottom: 0 none;
}
.dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
.dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
  background-color: #66615B;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  opacity: 1;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.dropdown-menu.dropdown-primary > li > a:hover, .dropdown-menu.dropdown-primary > li > a:focus {
  background-color: #7A9E9F;
}
.dropdown-menu.dropdown-info > li > a:hover, .dropdown-menu.dropdown-info > li > a:focus {
  background-color: #68B3C8;
}
.dropdown-menu.dropdown-success > li > a:hover, .dropdown-menu.dropdown-success > li > a:focus {
  background-color: #7AC29A;
}
.dropdown-menu.dropdown-warning > li > a:hover, .dropdown-menu.dropdown-warning > li > a:focus {
  background-color: #F3BB45;
}
.dropdown-menu.dropdown-danger > li > a:hover, .dropdown-menu.dropdown-danger > li > a:focus {
  background-color: #EB5E28;
}

.btn-group.select {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.btn-group.select.open {
  overflow: visible;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .navbar {
    min-height: 75px;
  }

  .navbar-form {
    margin-top: 21px;
    margin-bottom: 21px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
  }

  .navbar-search-form {
    display: none;
  }

  .navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu,
  .dropdown .dropdown-menu {
    transform: translate3d(0px, -40px, 0px);
    transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1) 0s, opacity 0.3s ease 0s, height 0s linear 0.35s;
  }

  .navbar-nav > li.open > .dropdown-menu, .dropdown.open .dropdown-menu {
    transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
  }

  .navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu:before {
    border-bottom: 11px solid #F1EAE0;
    border-left: 11px solid transparent;
    border-right: 11px solid transparent;
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 12px;
    top: -11px;
  }

  .navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu:after {
    border-bottom: 11px solid #FFFCF5;
    border-left: 11px solid transparent;
    border-right: 11px solid transparent;
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 12px;
    top: -10px;
  }

  .navbar-nav.navbar-left > li > .dropdown-menu:before {
    right: auto;
    left: 12px;
  }

  .navbar-nav.navbar-left > li > .dropdown-menu:after {
    right: auto;
    left: 12px;
  }

  .navbar .navbar-header {
    margin-left: 10px;
  }

  .footer:not(.footer-big) nav > ul li:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
  }

  body > .navbar-collapse.collapse {
    display: none !important;
  }

/*          Changes for small display      */
@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .sidebar {
    display: none;
  }

  .main-panel {
    width: 100%;
  }

  .navbar-transparent {
    padding-top: 15px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
  }

  body {
    position: relative;
  }

  h6 {
    font-size: 1em;
  }

  .wrapper {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0px, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0px, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0px, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0px, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.33s cubic-bezier(0.685, 0.0473, 0.346, 1);
    -moz-transition: all 0.33s cubic-bezier(0.685, 0.0473, 0.346, 1);
    -o-transition: all 0.33s cubic-bezier(0.685, 0.0473, 0.346, 1);
    -ms-transition: all 0.33s cubic-bezier(0.685, 0.0473, 0.346, 1);
    transition: all 0.33s cubic-bezier(0.685, 0.0473, 0.346, 1);
    left: 0;
    background-color: white;
  }

  .navbar .container {
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.33s cubic-bezier(0.685, 0.0473, 0.346, 1);
    -moz-transition: all 0.33s cubic-bezier(0.685, 0.0473, 0.346, 1);
    -o-transition: all 0.33s cubic-bezier(0.685, 0.0473, 0.346, 1);
    -ms-transition: all 0.33s cubic-bezier(0.685, 0.0473, 0.346, 1);
    transition: all 0.33s cubic-bezier(0.685, 0.0473, 0.346, 1);
    position: relative;
  }

  .navbar .navbar-collapse.collapse,
  .navbar .navbar-collapse.collapse.in,
  .navbar .navbar-collapse.collapsing {
    display: none !important;
  }

  .navbar-nav > li {
    float: none;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
  }

  .off-canvas-sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 230px;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1032;
    visibility: visible;
    background-color: #999;
    overflow-y: visible;
    border-top: none;
    text-align: left;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-left: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(230px, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(230px, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(230px, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(230px, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(230px, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.33s cubic-bezier(0.685, 0.0473, 0.346, 1);
    -moz-transition: all 0.33s cubic-bezier(0.685, 0.0473, 0.346, 1);
    -o-transition: all 0.33s cubic-bezier(0.685, 0.0473, 0.346, 1);
    -ms-transition: all 0.33s cubic-bezier(0.685, 0.0473, 0.346, 1);
    transition: all 0.33s cubic-bezier(0.685, 0.0473, 0.346, 1);
  }
  .off-canvas-sidebar .sidebar-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 3;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 100%;
    box-shadow: inset 1px 0px 0px 0px #DDDDDD;
  }
  .off-canvas-sidebar .nav {
    margin-top: 0;
    padding: 10px 15px 0;
  }
  .off-canvas-sidebar .nav > li > a {
    margin: 0px 0px;
    color: #66615B;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1.4em;
    padding: 10px 0;
  }
  .off-canvas-sidebar .nav > li > a:hover, .off-canvas-sidebar .nav > li > a.active {
    color: #403D39;
  }
  .off-canvas-sidebar .nav > li > a p,
  .off-canvas-sidebar .nav > li > a .notification,
  .off-canvas-sidebar .nav > li > a .caret {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .off-canvas-sidebar .nav > li > a .caret {
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    top: 12px;
  }
  .off-canvas-sidebar .nav > li > a i {
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    line-height: 26px;
  }
  .off-canvas-sidebar .nav > li.active > a:before {
    border-right: none;
    border-left: 12px solid #DDDDDD;
    border-top: 12px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 12px solid transparent;
    right: auto;
    margin-left: -15px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 10px;
  }
  .off-canvas-sidebar .nav > li.active > a:after {
    border-right: none;
    border-left: 12px solid #f4f3ef;
    border-top: 12px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 12px solid transparent;
    right: auto;
    margin-left: -15px;
    left: -1px;
    top: 10px;
  }
  .off-canvas-sidebar::after {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f4f3ef;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 0%, rgba(112, 112, 112, 0) 60%, rgba(186, 186, 186, 0.15) 100%);
    display: block;
    content: "";
    z-index: 1;
  }
  .off-canvas-sidebar.has-image::after {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgba(17, 17, 17, 0.8);
    display: block;
    content: "";
    z-index: 1;
  }
  .off-canvas-sidebar .logo {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 4;
    padding-top: 11px;
    padding-bottom: 11px;
  }
  .off-canvas-sidebar .divider {
    height: 1px;
    margin: 10px 0;
  }

  .nav-open .navbar-collapse {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0px, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0px, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0px, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0px, 0, 0);
  }

  .nav-open .navbar .container {
    left: -230px;
  }

  .nav-open .wrapper {
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-230px, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(-230px, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(-230px, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(-230px, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-230px, 0, 0);
  }

  .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    background: #fff;
    width: 24px;
    height: 2px;
    border-radius: 1px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }

  .navbar-header .navbar-toggle {
    margin: 10px 15px 10px 0;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
  }

  .navbar-nav {
    margin: 1px 0;
  }

  .dropdown-menu {
    display: none;
  }
  .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover, .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
    background-color: transparent;
  }

  .navbar-fixed-top {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  }

  .navbar-toggle:hover, .navbar-toggle:focus {
    background-color: transparent !important;
  }

  .btn.dropdown-toggle {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
  
  .navbar-collapse.collapse {
    height: 100% !important;
  }

  .navbar-collapse.collapse.in {
    display: block;
  }

  .navbar-header .collapse, .navbar-toggle {
    display: block !important;
  }

  .navbar-header {
    float: none;
  }

  .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu {
    position: static;
    float: none;
    width: auto;
    margin-top: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
  }

  .main-panel > .content {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
  }

  .nav .open > a, .nav .open > a:focus, .nav .open > a:hover {
    background-color: transparent;
  }

  .footer .copyright {
    padding: 0px 15px;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .table-full-width {
    margin-left: -15px;
    margin-right: -15px;
  }

  .table-responsive {
    overflow: visible;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .table-responsive {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="assets/img/apple-icon.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="assets/img/favicon.png">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />

    <title></title>

    <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' name='viewport' />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">

        <div class="sidebar" data-background-color="black" data-active-color="danger">

            <div class="sidebar-wrapper">
                <div class="logo">
                    <div style="margin:auto auto"><center><img src="../Images/logofb.png" / width="80px" height="40px"></center></div>
                </div>

            <ul class="nav">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#ordenes"  class="collapsed">
                            <p><i class="ti-user"></i> MENU<span class="ti-arrow-down"></span></p>

                        </a>
                        <div class="collapse" id="ordenes"  style="height: 0px;">
                            <ul class="nav nav-list">
                                <li><a href="#"><i class="ti-angle-right"></i> SUMMENU 1</a></li>

                                <li><a href="#"><i class="ti-angle-right"></i>SUBMENU 2</a></li>


                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#toggleDemo"  class="collapsed">

                            <p><i class="ti-user"></i>translado<span class="ti-arrow-down"></span></p>

                        </a>
                        <div class="collapse" id="toggleDemo"  style="height: 0px;">
                            <ul class="nav nav-list">

                                <li><a href="#"><i class="ti-angle-right"></i> SUMBMENU</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><i class="ti-angle-right"></i> SUMBMENU</a></li>
                                                           
                                <li><a href="#"><i class="ti-angle-right"></i> SUMBMENU</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><i class="ti-angle-right"></i> SUBMENU</a></li>

                                <li><a href="#"><i class="ti-angle-right"></i> SUBMENU</a></li>

                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#toggleDemonc"  class="collapsed">

                            <p><i class="ti-user"></i>N/C INMEDIATA FFC<span class="ti-arrow-down"></span></p>

                        </a>
                        <div class="collapse" id="toggleDemonc"  style="height: 0px;">
                            <ul class="nav nav-list">

                                <li><a href="#"><i class="ti-angle-right"></i> SUBMENU</a></li>

                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>

                </ul>

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="main-panel">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar bar1"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar bar2"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar bar3"></span>
                        </button>
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">sistema</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                    <i class="ti-user"></i>
                                    <p>usuario/p>
                                    <b class="caret"></b>

                                </a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="../cerrarSesion">Cerrar sesión</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>

            <div class="content">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="card">
                                <div class="header">
                                </div>
                                <div class="content">

                                    <div class="container-fluid" id="maximoPagina">

                                    </div>

                                    <div id="chartHours" class="ct-chart"></div>
                                    <div class="footer">
                                        <hr>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>


            <footer class="footer">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                </div>
            </footer>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aplica éste código al elemento `div class="sidebar-wrapper"`

[css](/questions/tagged/css)

```
<div class="sidebar-wrapper" style="
    background: black;
">
```

Comment: gracias bro si funcionó